# How to change default back button icon in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How I will change the back button icon in flutter using the theme. So it can be reflected throughout the application. I saw multiple options in the theme to change the size and color of the icon. But didn't see the change icon option.

Comment: It seems the only way is that you will create a custom widget and call it on every page. There is no option in the theme. Weird!

Comment: right. but if the flutter team adds this option.it is very useful for developers

Comment: You are absolutely right. There is another bad solution: you can change the icon on that Flutter package locally.

Comment: Flutter team will `not` do this because it violates standards of Material/Cupertino designs.

Answer (score 6):

Example:

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar(
    leading: BackButton(), // icon depends on TargetPlattrom
  ),
),
```

Or you can create your own constant widget basis on `IconButton` with your own icon settings, than use it as value for `leading` property. In addition, there is an `AppBarTheme` class, which can be used when you create instance of `ThemeData`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBarTheme-class.html

P.S. If you look at AppBar source code you see that regular widget `CloseButton` or `BackButton` are used. So there is no specific style for it. And you have 2 ways:

- Create your own global widget and use it in each Scaffold.
- Subclass Scaffold with your own leading property and use it.

Comment: AppBarTheme does not contain any icon option to change for the whole project.

Comment: not like this@BambinoUA. I know this leading option

Comment: @BambinoUA, Done from My end.

Answer (score 4):

You can override the back button icon using the global theme

```
ThemeData(
  actionIconTheme: ActionIconThemeData(
    backButtonIconBuilder: (BuildContext context) => SvgPicture.asset('assets/arrow-back-ios.svg'),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom AppBar and reuse it.If you want to handle the automatic imply property call **canPop** function like below:-

```
            AppBar(
            leading: ModalRoute.of(context)!.canPop
                ? IconButton(
                    onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios)
                  )
                : null,    
            title: Text("Test"),
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
appBar: AppBar(
              automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
              leading: Builder(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return IconButton(
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.alarm_on), // Put icon of your preference.
                    onPressed: () {
                      // your method (function), 
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
              title: Text(widget.title),
              centerTitle: true,
```

The above code will change the default back icon to alarm on icon. You can change it to any thing.

Comment: @Mr vd, If you like it please vote and select my answer.

Comment: bro. I clearly mention I want to change the back button in the whole app. only using a theme is possible. I know this solution using leading. this will change only the current page. using a custom back button widget it can be achievable but its a long procedure

Comment: Ok, I need one clarification before, I can answer this question. Do you need ```Icons.arrow_back``` anywhere in your application? for Now or Future..

Comment: @Mrvd, And please remove negative vote. My reputation points are low. I used them on bounty.

Comment: @Vinay H P, let's help each other? You upvote my answer, I will upvote yours one.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job for you:

```
IconButton(
  onPressed: (){
    Navigator.pop(context);
  },
  icon:Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios), 
  //replace with our own icon data.
  )
```

For the future seekers like me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this. I'm still learning and I don't know if this will work in all cases. I've done this using VS Code while my app is in development.

I looked up the backbutton references(Shift + Alt + F12) and found the actual button in flutter sdk. I changed it there in the `back_button.dart` file which can be found in your flutter installation folder : `c:\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\back_button.dart`

There, edit the static IconData method of the button and choose any Icon you wanna use for any platform.

```
  static IconData _getIconData(TargetPlatform platform) {
    switch (platform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        return Icons.arrow_back_ios;
    }
  }
```

In the above case Icons.arrow_back_ios will be returned in all platforms. You can specify the return Icon for each platform.

However, I haven't tested this in like a real world "production use" situation so I hope someone else here can clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple answer:

```
child: Icon(
              Icons.expand_more_rounded, // You can replace this with the desired icon
              size: 100.0, // Set your desired icon size
              color: Colors.blue,
              // Set your desired icon color
            ),
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this over the previous approaches suggested in this thread?